# facial landmark deduction compatible with blender?

Tags: scripting, command-line

I'm trying to to get dlib integrated with blender for over 3 months. Is there any other facial landmark detection that I could integrate with blender? or is there a method to get dlib working in blender? Ive tried everything I could think of.

thanks pascal

Comment: I imagine [dlib](http://dlib.net/face_detector.py.html) just takes a raster image and spits out the most probable contours face, nose, mouth, eyes, ears) as 2d locations/pixel on the raster? Are you looking to implement something that will run on video or just single frames?

Comment: You should mention whether you are able to get dlib running independently of Blender. (to show that you were able to satisfy those dependencies)